# Run specific Android instrumentation test with Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I need to execute certain Android test case (Class or method) with gradle from console.
It is located at *src/androidTest/java/com/example/CertainTest.java*.

Android Studio makes this available via complicated `adb shell am instrument`.

Is it possible to invoke certain Android Test only via Gradle?

I have read about [How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22505533/5091346), [Test from the Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html) but is it quite complicated way of doing that.

This is how Android Studio launches specific Test Class:

```
Launching Tests
$ adb push /.../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.andrii.espressotutorial
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.andrii.espressotutorial"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.andrii.espressotutorial
Success
$ adb push /.../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.andrii.espressotutorial.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.andrii.espressotutorial.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.andrii.espressotutorial.test
Success
Running tests
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.example.andrii.espressotutorial.ExampleInstrumentedTest2 com.example.andrii.espressotutorial.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Tests ran to completion.
```

Comment: perhaps just wrap those adb commands into a custom gradle task.

Comment: Check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288448/how-to-retrieve-path-to-adb-in-build-gradle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a specific instrumentation unit test with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565857/running-a-specific-instrumentation-unit-test-with-gradle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a gradle task like this:

In the main gradle file

```
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-integration-tests.gradle"
```

Then create a directory tools and a file script-integration-tests.gradle in the project directory. Then fill it with the test class name like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

task integrationTest(type: Exec) {
    def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'instrument', '-w', '-r', '-e',
            'debug', 'false', '-e', 'class', 'de.app.id.PullRequestTests',
            'de.app.id.app_test.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
```

Comment: Then run the intergration tests as a gradle task ./gradlew intergrationTest