# Where does Android Studio Gradle actually take path variables from?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, path, environment-variables

TLDR: Would like gradle build to use my environment variables.

I am building an application using Gradle for Android and am using `commandLine 'adb', 'get-state'`
It fails and says it cannot find adb.
`A problem occurred starting process 'command 'adb''`

This is weird as Android Studio can find ADB and uses it to show the device explorer and perform debugging.

When I do `sudo apt install adb` it works, but that's because there is an installation of ADB at the paths gradle is looking at.

When I replace `command 'adb'` with `commman '<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'`, it works, but I would not like to commit my local paths to a shared repo. I would like Gradle to use the correct paths from my system.

I have $ANDROID_HOME set up correctly

My $PATH from bash includes

```
<user>/Android/Sdk/tools
<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
<user>/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
<user>/Android/Sdk/tools
<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
<user>/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

Running on `which adb` on bash retruns `<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Running this on Gradle return this:

```
task environment(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'env'
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
PATH=<user>/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:<user>/.dotnet/tools:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

```
task testAndroidHome() {
    println "${-> System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")}"
}
```

OUTPUT

```
> Configure project :
null
```

As you can see, all Android tools are not in my gradle environment, regardless of being on my bash path.

BASHRC

```
# Android Paths
export ANDROID_HOME=<user>/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

I am running `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` as my jdk, when I run `System.out.println(System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME"));`, compiled and run within my bash termianl, I get `<user>/Android/Sdk`.

---

ANDROID STUDIO SETTINGS:
[image: Environment Variables on Android Studio contain path.]

[image: Gradle Settings]

---

None of the solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288448/how-to-retrieve-path-to-adb-in-build-gradle) work. def adb = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb" gives me `'null/platform-tools/adb'`

And the following gives me this:

```
    def androidPlugin = project.plugins.findPlugin("android")
    def adb = androidPlugin.sdkHandler.sdkInfo?.adb
```

`Cannot get property 'sdkHandler' on null object`

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288448/how-to-retrieve-path-to-adb-in-build-gradle

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, none of the solutions on there work.
`def adb = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb"` gives me ` 'null/platform-tools/adb'`

And the following gives me this:
`def androidPlugin = project.plugins.findPlugin("android")def adb = androidPlugin.sdkHandler.sdkInfo?.adb`

`Cannot get property 'sdkHandler' on null object`